# Xamarin iOS app freezes: ViewDidAppear() never gets called

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, rendering

This seems to be a tricky one:

We're working on a Xamarin iOS app that has a `UITableView` control displaying a list of profiles. Once the user clicks on one of the profiles we'd like to switch to a separate "ProfileViewController" to display more detailed information. This works just fine for `99.9%` of the time. In the remaining `~0.1%` the item in the list gets highlighted (which happens OnClick) but the app just seemingly freezes and never switches to the other `ViewController`, leaving the user with an unresponsive list.
The interesting thing to note here is that the app doesn't really freeze, as the simple "swipe back" gesture brings the user back to the `UITableView` (to be clear the switch-to-profile-viewcontroller animation is never played so it basically switches from the unresponsive list back to the same list, but now it is responsive again).

The tricky thing is that we can't reliably reproduce this bug. It just seems to happen at random, sometimes while stuff is running in the background, other times while the app was previously in an idle state. We are pretty sure that it isn't related to multithreading (we triple-checked everything, using locking and semaphores where necessary), it rather seems to be some rendering issue (as you can still swipe back to the previous screen or at least it isn't your common dead lock).

Using a bunch of `Console.WriteLine()` tracers and hours of trial and error reproducing this bug we could isolate the problem and discovered the following:

Upon clicking on the list code in `ViewDidLoad()` and `ViewWillAppear()` is successfully executed. However `ViewDidAppear()` never gets invoked. There is nothing else happening in our code or on different threads between `ViewWillAppear()` and `ViewDidAppear()` and we don't have any funky / unusual code that gets executed previously (just the usual UI initialization like this in `ViewDidLoad()`):

```csharp
...

LblProfileName.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
LblProfileName.Text = string.Empty;
LblProfileName.Font = FontAgent.ForSize(30);

LblProfileSlogan.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
LblProfileSlogan.Text = string.Empty;
LblProfileSlogan.Font = FontAgent.ForSize(20);

LblProfileRelationInfo.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
LblProfileRelationInfo.Text = string.Empty;
LblProfileRelationInfo.Font = FontAgent.ForSize(15);

...
```

At this point we are kinda out of ideas as to what could be going wrong here and we have independently reviewed any of our code that could remotely be involved in this bug but we found nothing.

We didn't find anything related online but maybe someone else has encountered a similar issue like this in Xamarin / Xamarin iOS before?
Are there any steps we could take that we don't know of? When breaking the app in the Visual Studio for Mac debugger during the freezes the call stacks only contain native code and are not of much use.

Any help or ideas as to what else we could try are hugely appreciated :)

### Edit: Adding some code

This is our `BaseViewController` defining some initialization methods to be used by it's children (again in `99.9%` of all cases this works just fine):

```csharp
public abstract class BaseViewController : UIViewController
{
    public BaseViewController(string nibName, NSBundle nSBundle) : base(nibName, nSBundle)
    {
        ControllerDidInitialize();
    }

    public ClubmappViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        ControllerDidInitialize();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        CustomOrientationService.ScreenRotationPortrait();
        InitializeStaticContent();
        Console.WriteLine("ViewDidLoad() exits just fine...");
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
        Console.WriteLine("When the bug occurs this never gets executed :C");
        RefreshUI();
        OnViewDidAppear?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        LoadData();
    }
    
    private protected abstract void InitializeStaticContent();

    private protected abstract void RefreshUI();

    private protected virtual void LoadData()
    {
    }

    private protected virtual void ControllerDidInitialize()
    {
    }
}
```

This is the `ProfileViewController` that inherits from `BaseViewController` and that just stops being rendered or inititialized or whatever the actual problem might be (it just never shows up as described above) but most of the time it works just fine:

```csharp
public partial class ProfileViewController : BaseViewController
{
    public const string STORYBOARD_ID = "ProfileViewController";

    public ProfileViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    private protected override void ControllerDidInitialize()
    {
        // do initialization things like initializing variables, etc
        // no real logic here
    }

    private protected override void InitializeStaticContent()
    {
        // layouting loading
        LblProfileTitle.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        LblProfileTitle.Text = string.Empty;
        LblProfileTitle.Font = FontAgent.ForSize(20);
        LblProfileTitle.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(20);

        LblProfileName.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        LblProfileName.Text = string.Empty;
        LblProfileName.Font = FontAgent.ForSize(30);

        LblProfileSlogan.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        LblProfileSlogan.Text = string.Empty;
        LblProfileSlogan.Font = FontAgent.ForSize(20);
        // ... and so on ..
    }

    private protected override void RefreshUI()
    {
        // ... theme related stuff ...
        ViewProfileActive.BackgroundColor = ThemeAgent.CurrentTheme.OnlineIndicatorColor;
        LblProfileName.TextColor = ThemeAgent.CurrentTheme.PrimaryTextColor;
        LblProfileSlogan.TextColor = ThemeAgent.CurrentTheme.SecondaryTextColor;
        // ...
    }

    private protected async override void LoadData()
    {
        // load user data ...
        ProfileData data = await ...
    }
}
```

And this is the "OnClick" event that is triggered when a profile is clicked on, that's supposed to initialize and show the `ProfileViewController` (it's unlikely that something's wrong with this but including it nonetheless):

```csharp
// ...
(sender, e) =>
{
    ProfileViewController profileController = (ProfileViewController)UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null).InstantiateViewController(ProfileViewController.STORYBOARD_ID);
    profileController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
    currentViewController.NavigationController.PushViewController(profileController, true);
}
// ...
```

Comment: Did you call `base.ViewDidAppear()`? Can you please create a new blank page and navigate to that pages to check if the ViewDidAppear triggered in new page?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I added the most relevant parts of our code to the question. We do call `base.ViewDidAppear()` and most of the time everything works fine and then again sometimes it doesn't. We have other view controllers inheriting from `BaseViewController` where this bug never occurs and even on this `ProfileViewController` `ViewDidAppear` usually triggers the ways it's supposed to.

Comment: Put some delay - await Task.Delay(200); and load the UI object initialize in the detail viewcontroller